# How to add Google Translate button on Angular web app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-translate

Is it possible to translate the angular web page using Google Translate Script?
or any other solution to translate dynamic content without using google translate API.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```